# Recipe directions to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making a recipe site. In the database I have recipes directions saved. They all have some numbering like the example below. How can i get the recipe into array based on the numbers? I was thinking of using \n as a explode value, but I instead want to use the numbers (1. 2. 3. 4. 5. etc).

My code:

```
<?php
$get_recipe_directions = "
1. Rinse the noodles, bla bla bla.
2. Spray a bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla.
3. Add the shrimp, bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla.

Serve with jam and rice.";

// I need to explode the recipe directions to array based on 
// the numbers
$array = explode("??", $get_recipe_directions);

for($x=0;$x<sizeof($array);$x++){
    echo"<li>$array[$x]</li>\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$array= preg_split('/\d+\./', $get_recipe_directions);
```

;-)

it's regex-based splitting of string.

see php "preg_split"

Comment: @AbraCadaver for case insensitive digits. ;)